# Could not open X display, XDG_Runtime_DIR Error:

Tags: graphics, nautilus, gtk, display-manager, xdg

Output from terminal from where i tried to run nautilus and read an external drive.
Also, i got a terminal window before logging in that system is running under log graphics mode, i will have to login using terminal or something like that and my login screen never came up so i used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> logged in as root and used

```
service lightdm restart
```

and then tried to back my data so that i could format ubuntu because of so many errors after installing 14.04 
i got this error -

```
(nautilus:3688): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 1.6.2
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '/media/deadman/H LADDHA/ubuntu-backup2/Desktop/5_6sem_BE_CSE_Syllabus_2013-141.pdf': Permission denied.
Error loading document: Error opening file: Permission denied

(nautilus:3688): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: Unable to create loader for mime type application/pdf: Unrecognized image file format

(nautilus:3688): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: Error creating thumbnail for file:///media/deadman/H%20LADDHA/ubuntu-backup2/Desktop/5_6sem_BE_CSE_Syllabus_2013-141.pdf: Unrecognized image file format
No protocol specified

** (evince:3922): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```